# What happens if the system is off when there is a task scheduled in rufus-scheduler?

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

In the context of a gem running as a daemon and relying on rufus-scheduler to run tasks at specific intervals: will the scheduler run the task when the laptop is back on/awake if it was off at the time the task was scheduled to run?

i.e. does it behave the same as a cronjob where if you miss your time because the system is off, then it won't run until the next time; or will it run asap after the scheduled time if it wasn't able to run then?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `cron` schedule, rufus-scheduler will run at the next matching time.

An `every` schedule should "bomb" and try to trigger for every occurrence that happened while off.

An `interval` schedule should trigger then trigger next after the interval time elapsed.

For another type of schedule (`at`, `in`), it should trigger when the system is back on.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer!